# Rest Connector with JSON

Tags: json, oracle, rest, oracle-ebs, mcs

I have created a REST connector in oracle MCS. It works fine if we give the body in text/xml format. I want to know whether we can use the body in json format or not(I want to access EBS using the connector).
I have attached a snapshot of the connector i have created[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. The accept-type header will matter to tell the service to return JSON if this is not the default for your REST service

Frank